# Removing special characters from JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a JSON File with 3 objects like this:

`[{"ID": "44585", "TITLE": "A day in *Australia*=/", "MailThread":           [{"email": " Its a great day, isn't it."}, {"email": " Yes, indeed."}, {"email": " Great Day!!!"}], "SUMMARY": "", "NAME": "Mike's Journal", "PRIORITY": 3, "FLIGHTTICKETNO": 25565826, "CODENAME": "ausTrip", "DESC": "I am really feeling great*&^% to be here!! I love this place, and find it's places amazin#@$. Thanks!!"},{"ID": "44585", "TITLE": "A day in *Australia*=/", "MailThread":           [{"email": " Its a great day, isn't it."}, {"email": " Yes, indeed."}, {"email": " Great Day!!!"}], "SUMMARY": "", "NAME": "Mike's Journal", "PRIORITY": 3, "FLIGHTTICKETNO": 25565826, "CODENAME": "ausTrip", "DESC": "I am really feeling great*&^% to be here!! I love this place, and find it's places amazin#@$. Thanks!!"},{"ID": "44585", "TITLE": "A day in *Australia*=/", "MailThread":           [{"email": " Its a great day, isn't it."}, {"email": " Yes, indeed."}, {"email": " Great Day!!!"}], "SUMMARY": "", "NAME": "Mike's Journal", "PRIORITY": 3, "FLIGHTTICKETNO": 25565826, "CODENAME": "ausTrip", "DESC": "I am really feeling great*&^% to be here!! I love this place, and find it's places amazin#@$. Thanks!!"}]`

I need to remove special characters like *=/,&^#@ from TITLE, multiple emails in MailThread and DESC from all 3 objects and write the edited to a new json file.

Comment: Output is dataframe? Or json? Can you add desired output?

Comment: Output is json..just edited the query..kindly look again!!

Comment: "I need a steak" is not a question.

Comment: This is what I am trying to do                                                              `import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('JsonData')
jsonobj = df['TITLE']

for i in jsonobj:
   jsonobj[i].replace('[','')
   
print(jsonobj)
` And its not working, maybe this is not asking for a steak but help!!

Comment: You say you need to remove **multiple emails in MailThread**. Do you mean to remove all of them or selected? State that clearly, it will be good if you give exact output.

Comment: I need to remove special characters like *=/,&^#@ from the emails present inside MailThread.

Answer (score 0):

Only handle **TITLE**, if you want something else, please handle it youeself as follow:

```
$ python demo.py
{'PRIORITY': 3, 'TITLE': 'A day in Australia', 'FLIGHTTICKETNO': 25565826, 'MailThread': [{'email': " Its a great day, isn't it."}, {'email': ' Yes, indeed.'}, {'email': ' Great Day!!!'}], 'CODENAME': 'ausTrip', 'SUMMARY': '', 'NAME': "Mike's Journal", 'ID': '44585', 'DESC': "I am really feeling great*&^% to be here!! I love this place, and find it's places amazin#@$. Thanks!!"}
{'PRIORITY': 3, 'TITLE': 'A day in Australia', 'FLIGHTTICKETNO': 25565826, 'MailThread': [{'email': " Its a great day, isn't it."}, {'email': ' Yes, indeed.'}, {'email': ' Great Day!!!'}], 'CODENAME': 'ausTrip', 'SUMMARY': '', 'NAME': "Mike's Journal", 'ID': '44585', 'DESC': "I am really feeling great*&^% to be here!! I love this place, and find it's places amazin#@$. Thanks!!"}
{'PRIORITY': 3, 'TITLE': 'A day in Australia', 'FLIGHTTICKETNO': 25565826, 'MailThread': [{'email': " Its a great day, isn't it."}, {'email': ' Yes, indeed.'}, {'email': ' Great Day!!!'}], 'CODENAME': 'ausTrip', 'SUMMARY': '', 'NAME': "Mike's Journal", 'ID': '44585', 'DESC': "I am really feeling great*&^% to be here!! I love this place, and find it's places amazin#@$. Thanks!!"}
```

### Code

```
#!/usr/bin/python


def func(title):
    for ch in "*=/,&^#@":
        title = title.replace(ch, '')
    return title


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = [{'CODENAME': 'ausTrip',
            'DESC': "I am really feeling great*&^% to be here!! I love this place, and find it's places amazin#@$. Thanks!!",
            'FLIGHTTICKETNO': 25565826,
            'ID': '44585',
            'MailThread': [{'email': " Its a great day, isn't it."},
                                {'email': ' Yes, indeed.'},
                                {'email': ' Great Day!!!'}],
            'NAME': "Mike's Journal",
            'PRIORITY': 3,
            'SUMMARY': '',
            'TITLE': 'A day in *Australia*=/'},
            {'CODENAME': 'ausTrip',
                'DESC': "I am really feeling great*&^% to be here!! I love this place, and find it's places amazin#@$. Thanks!!",
                'FLIGHTTICKETNO': 25565826,
                'ID': '44585',
                'MailThread': [{'email': " Its a great day, isn't it."},
                                {'email': ' Yes, indeed.'},
                                {'email': ' Great Day!!!'}],
                'NAME': "Mike's Journal",
                'PRIORITY': 3,
                'SUMMARY': '',
                'TITLE': 'A day in *Australia*=/'},
            {'CODENAME': 'ausTrip',
                'DESC': "I am really feeling great*&^% to be here!! I love this place, and find it's places amazin#@$. Thanks!!",
                'FLIGHTTICKETNO': 25565826,
                'ID': '44585',
                'MailThread': [{'email': " Its a great day, isn't it."},
                                {'email': ' Yes, indeed.'},
                                {'email': ' Great Day!!!'}],
                'NAME': "Mike's Journal",
                'PRIORITY': 3,
                'SUMMARY': '',
                'TITLE': 'A day in *Australia*=/'}]


    for item in data:
        if item and 'TITLE' in item.keys():
            title = func(item['TITLE'])
            item['TITLE'] = title
            print(item)
```